# DiscordJS Message property 'find' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js, undefined

I'd like your help on my code: I'm trying to create a Discord bot, and I have a problem in my message event.

When a user send a command that doesn't exist, the step of checking if the command exists (and then possibly executing it) returns me an error  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`.
From what I understand is that he can't execute the `find` method on `client.commands` since it would be `undefined`, except that I've checked with `console.log` and the `client.commands` has all the commands and is not `undefined`...



main.js (the `client` variable used in message.js comes from here)

```js
const { Client, Collection } = require('discord.js');
const { loadCommands, loadEvents } = require('./utils/loader');
const { TOKEN } = require('./config');

const client = new Client();
['commands', 'cooldowns'].forEach(x => client[x] = new Collection());

loadCommands(client);
loadEvents(client);

client.login(TOKEN);
```

message.js (file of the message event)

```js
const { Collection } = require('discord.js'); // Retrieving DiscordJS functionalities
const { PREFIX } = require('../../config'); // Retrieving the information contained in the file 'config.js'

module.exports = (client, message) => {
    
    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX) || message.author.bot) return; // Ignore the message if it's not a command
    const args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).split(/ +/); // Arguments can be found within the command
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase(); // We establish the command that is requested
    const user = message.mentions.users.first();

    // Check if the requested command exists
    // THE ERROR IS ON THE LINE BELOW
    const command = client.commands.get(commandName) || client.commmands.find(cmd => cmd.help.aliases && cmd.help.aliases.includes(commandName));
    if (!command) return;

    [...]

    // Execution of the command
    command.run(client, message, args);
    
}
```

The error that is returned in the console

```js
D:\Developpement\Chamiro\events\client\message.js:11
    const command = client.commands.get(commandName) || client.commmands.find(cmd => cmd.help.aliases && cmd.help.aliases.includes(commandName));
                                                                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
    at module.exports (D:\Developpement\Chamiro\events\client\message.js:11:74)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (D:\Developpement\Chamiro\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (D:\Developpement\Chamiro\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (D:\Developpement\Chamiro\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (D:\Developpement\Chamiro\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (D:\Developpement\Chamiro\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (D:\Developpement\Chamiro\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (D:\Developpement\Chamiro\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:797:20)
```

A little help would be nice :)
Thanks

Comment: You've used `commmands` with 3 `m` instead of 2.

Comment: I feel like hitting myself... Thank you Titus, I've been trying for hours and hours trying to understand, and I had not seen, I'm a jerk ^^

Answer (score 0):

looks like a spelling mistake in line 11. commands was written there with 3x "m"